# Excel Combine Cell Strings and Ignore Blank Values

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, concatenation

I have 3 columns of data that I want to combine into the format AAAA.BB-CC

Columns A and B will always have values, but column C is optional. In that case, I want to ignore the blanks and have the result written as AAAA.BB

The problem I have with my formula as it is now, is that the "-" will always show, even if column C is blank

```
='Set-Up'!$B$4 &"." &[MMC Code] & "-"&[Sub MMC Code]
```

The AAA portion comes from a different sheet, and is the same value down the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an IF()

```
='Set-Up'!$B$4 &"." &[MMC Code] & IF([Sub MMC Code]<>"","-"&[Sub MMC Code],"")
```

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfectly/

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM('Set-Up'!$B$4&"."&[MMC Code]&" "&[Sub MMC Code])," ","-")
```